# How to compare an Integer using least code?

Tags: java

There is an Integer property called foo in a model. Now I need to know whether it equals 1 or 2. Usually I use:

```
if (null != model) {
    Integer foo = model.getFoo();
    if (foo != null) {
        if (foo == 1) {
            // do something...
        }
        if (foo == 2) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any handier code to avoid the NullPointerException?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(1).equals(foo)`, `Integer.valueOf(2).equals(foo)`

Comment: (Integer)model.getFoo().compareTo(1) , (Integer)model.getFoo().compareTo(2)

Comment: @ShivendraGupta what if `model.getFoo()` is `null`?

Comment: @ShivendraGupta That will still NPE.

Comment: @ShivendraGupta that would still throw `NullPointerException` if `foo` is `null`, and is essentially the same as `foo == 1`, `foo == 2`.

Comment: Somebody gave the answer ..i would also recommened the use of optional @Thilo

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(model)
        .map(Model::getFoo)
        .ifPresent(foo -> {
            switch (foo) { // or if-else-if, the important thing is you skip the null check
                case 1: 
                    ...
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ...
                    break;
                ...
            }

        });
```

Comment: Note that this eliminates *both* null checks, not just the one OP did not like.

Comment: @Thilo isn't skipping both null checks better than skipping just one? I guess it depends on the actual use case.

Comment: Yes, this was meant as praise. You overachieved!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the null-safe `java.util.Object.equals`:

```
if(null != model) {
   Integer foo = model.getFoo();

   if(Objects.equals(foo, 1){
       //do something
   }
   if(Objects.equals(foo, 2){
       //do something
   }
}
```

The method has this description:

> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise, equality is determined by using the equals method of the first argument.

Comment: Why is no one using `else-if` ?

Comment: @Thilo I shouldn't assume it's an oversight in the original code, thought it's doing different things in those blocks

Answer (score 1):

You could do `Integer.of(1).equals(foo)`, but this is a bit silly. Why save the one line? I'd just put it inside the same `if/else-if` chain (and if that gets long, conside a `switch/case` (which also is not null-safe, though).

```
if (foo == null)
else if (foo == 1)
else if (foo == 2)
```

Also note that comparing objects with `==` is a bit tricky because of how auto-boxing works (or does not work). I *think* that it works in this case, but I do not want to have to think about it too hard, so in my code I usually drop down to `int` (after the null check) to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the code to like this:

```
 if (null != model) {
        Integer foo = model.getFoo();
            if (Integer.valueOf(1).equals(foo)) {
                // do something...
            }
            if (Integer.valueOf(2).equals(foo)) {
                // do something...
            }

}
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: I will do Update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming possible value is only `1` or `2`
Of course the model the should be guarded with null check
**Use ternary operator**

```
Model theModel = model.getFoo() ;

if(model!=null && model.getFoo()!=null){
   model.getFoo() == 1 ? callOne() : call2();
}
```

Comment: @Thilo I assumed the null check will be retained.

Comment: Updated the answer with null checks.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't return null sentinels values, and instead used [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)s, you could do:

```
Optional<Model> model = getModel();
Optional<Integer> foo = model.flatMap(Model::getFoo);
foo.filter(Integer.valueOf(1)::equals).ifPresent(this::doSomething);
foo.filter(Integer.valueOf(2)::equals).ifPresent(this::doSomethingElse);
```